# Scroll Rect scrolls simply due to mouse movement. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse, scrollrect

Unity 2019.1.0f2

Input System 1.0.2

1. I create an empty 3D project, then import the Input System into it.
2. I add EventSystem to the scene.
3. Then I write a simple script and add it to scene:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
    
    public class TestScroll : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Update()
        {
            Debug.Log(Mouse.current.scroll.ReadValue());
        }
    }
```

4. Then I run the scene and just move my mouse (don't spin the mouse wheel) and see this in the console:

[image]

Also in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Mouse.html) for the Input System I found this:

[image]

Because of this feature Scroll Rect starts to scroll simply because I move the mouse pointer over it.

How can this be avoided and why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a Unity bug: [topic](https://forum.unity.com/threads/new-input-system-%20and-scroll-rect-bug-when-clicking-on-scrollbar.840868/)